# Backendless error in hosted custom service

Tags: java, swift, backendless

I am trying to use a `hosted custom service` in `Backendless`

I created a custom `jar library`and uploaded it in `Backendless hosted custom service` but it's returning me an error when I try to invoke it using the SDK in Swift.

My Library is below:

SalvarContatosLibrary.java

```
package com.mbaas.service;

import com.backendless.Backendless;
import com.backendless.servercode.IBackendlessService;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SalvarContatoLibrary implements IBackendlessService {

    public boolean salvarContatos(ArrayList<Contato> contato) {

        boolean retorno = true;

        if(contatos == null || contatos() == 0) {
            retorno = false;
        } else {
            for(Contato contato: contatos) {
                Backendless.Persistence.save(contato);
            }
        }

        return retorno;
    }
}
```

Contato.java

```
package com.mbaas.service;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by guilhermedupas on 12/07/17.
 */

public class Contato {

    private Usuario usuario;
    private int prioridade;

    private String objectId;
    private Date created;
    private Date updated;
    private String ownerId;
}
```

Usuario.java

```
package com.mbaas.service;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by guilhermedupas on 12/07/17.
 */

public class Usuario {

    private String nome;
    private String foto;
    private Date dataNascimento;
    private String numeroTelefone;
    private String telefoneE164;

    private String objectId;
    private Date created;
    private Date updated;
    private String ownerId;
}
```

And I am trying to invoke the method as the code below:

Swift Code

```
func salvarContato() {

    let nomeServico = "SalvarContatoLibrary"
    let versaoServico = "1.0.0"
    let metodoServico = "salvarContatos"

    let contatosNSArray = contatos as! NSArray

    backendless?.customService.invoke(nomeServico, serviceVersion: versaoServico, method: metodoServico, args: contatosNSArray as! [Any],
        response: { (result: Any?) -> Void in
            print(result)

    }, error: { (fault: Fault?) -> Void in
        print("Erro contatos")
        print("Server reported an error to save the User: \(fault)")
    })
}
```

The error it's returning is:

`Server reported an error to save the User: Optional(FAULT = '0' [ExceptionClass:"CodeRunnerException"  {Msg:"Wrong number of arguments", Cause:"none"}] <ExceptionClass:"CodeRunnerException"  {Msg:"Wrong number of arguments", Cause:"none"}> )`

UPDATE:

No, `contatosNSArray` is not empty.

I tried now casting `contatos` to `NSMutableArray`

`contatosNSMutableArray = contatos as! NSMutableArray`

and it stoped retuning me the error but It's returning a response as a number `0` and it is not saving the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is from the Backendless support:

> Swift code generation for version 3 does not work correctly.
>
> I would recommend the following approach:
>
> 1. Modify your java code so it either declares public fields or get/set methods for the private fields.
> 2. Create the jar for the service and deploy in the 4.0 app. This is so you can generate the Swift code for it.
> 3. Once the swift code is generated, use it with your 3.x app.